# Can i install Android Studio and SDK in another Disk not the "C"?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I installed **Android Studio** and the **SDK** about a month ago in another Disk not the **"C"** it worked successfully but when i setup a new **Windows 7 (32bit)** it didn't work and gave me these error messages from both **Android** **Studio** and **SDK** .
[image]

[image]

i had to install both **Android Studio** and **SDK** in the **"C"** Disk to make it work
but i don't have **enough space** in the **"C"** Disk and i still have to install some staff from the **SDK** .

so is there is a way to install it in another Disk ?

Comment: Yes you can set the installation paths in the android studio setup.

Comment: i know that i can change the installation paths but when i do it doesn't work and gives me the error messages you see above ,, i'm asking if i can change something to make it work when i install it in another disk

Comment: try to open the studio.exe, not the batch file

Comment: i do that i open studio.exe not studio64.exe and the picture above shows the error appears when i do that

Comment: Please take care of your writing, in your sentence you do not care the capitalization and punctuation, e.g: i=I, try=Try etc...

Comment: @mohamedahmed Try reinstalling JDK. Also take note of the following:
1) Make sure the Java Environmental Variables are set.
2) If you have a 32-bit JDK installed, try to launch studio.exe and not studio64.exe.
3) You can keep your SDK where ever you want. Just point Android Studio to your SDK location once you open it.

Comment: Download only SKD from developer page and then unzip where you wont and set up you AS to this new SDK

Comment: you can install in any path you like @mohamedahmed

Comment: no i can't install it in any places but the "C" if i installed it in another disk it would gave me errors

Comment: @Lukáš Šálek i tried that but also the SDK should be in the "C" Disk to run

Comment: @mohamedahmed open studio.exe.vmoption and write `-vm D:/installed/jdk/bin`(this is your installed java path) save it then start file

Comment: `JDK_HOME` with value ` c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\ `

Comment: i have already added JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME with value C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\

Comment: @mohamedahmed Can you try copying 'AVD Manager.exe'and 'SDK Manager.exe' from "SDK_ROOT_FOLDER/tools/lib/" into the root SDK folder. Open SDK Manager.exe and see if you get the same error

Comment: @mohsinazeem #

# please add it to your user specific configuration file.
#
# See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration
#
-server
-Xms256m
-Xmx750m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-da
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.1
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio

Comment: @SuhaylSH i tried that too man before install it in "C" disk but it gave me the same error

Comment: @mohamedahmed can you share the screenshot of your SDK folder.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/a/hnTUG)